# Set href ="#" or unset html::a href from grid-view yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have the following code:

```
 [   'format' => 'raw',
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 5px;'],
            'value' => function($model) {
                if($model->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id) {
                    return  Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>',[''],['id'=> 'replay-to-'. $model->ID_KOMENTAR ]).' '. 
                            Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>', ['update', 'id' => $model->id]).' '.
                            Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], ['data' => ['confirm' => 'Do you really want to delete this element?','method' => 'post']]);
                }
                return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>',['feedback', 'id' => $model->id],['id'=> 'replay-to-'. $model->ID_KOMENTAR ]);
            },
        ],
```

I would like the replay button to avoid the href which makes my page redirect to another page because I want to click and put jquery there.

I tried with this :

```
Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>',[''],['id'=> 'replay-to-'. $model->ID_KOMENTAR ])
```

but it still redirects to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `href` value to `#`:

```
Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>', '#', ['id'=> 'replay-to-' . $model->ID_KOMENTAR]);
```

The HTML output will be:

```
<a id="replay-to-1" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a>
```

To completely remove `href` attribute use `null` (and it's default value of second paremeter):

```
Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>', null, ['id'=> 'replay-to-' . $model->ID_KOMENTAR]);
```

The HTML output will be:

```
<a id="replay-to-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>', false, ['id'=> 'replay-to-'. $model->ID_KOMENTAR ]);`

Comment: Yes, for complete attribute removal `false` is also acceptable.